# apache thrift async c++ client

Tags: thrift

I need an example which demonstrates how to create asyncronous apache thrift c++ client. [In this similar  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344431/apache-thrift-c-async-client) there is only an example of nonblicking server.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you are looking for. You want a client that makes multiple asynchronous requests to a non-blocking server? Or you want a client that just "works" with a non-blocking server.

Comment: @MarcDiMillo Seems to me that he wants to have the client async.  There is no special work required to be a client of the TNonblock server except that (I think) you need to use TFramedTransport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by async client he means to be able to call remote service without waiting for the response, and set some kind of callback when it arrives.

It requires changes in the service interface and the way service is called. Unfortunately I don't see a full solution in the thrift C++ library right now. There's only some limited support in async directory and cob-style option in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

How the server handles requests is independent from the client, you just need to use, as nHed previously said, TFramedTransport. Clients can connect to any type of server.