# Sample usage of TThreadPoolServer

Tags: thrift

I am trying to port an application that uses `TThreadedServer` to use `TThreadPoolServer`. I am currently using the class this way:

```
TThreadPoolServer server(
      processor),
      server_transport,
      transport_factory,
      protocol_factory);

  server.serve()
```

I get the following exception when the client tries to connect:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'apache::thrift::concurrency::IllegalStateException'   what(): 
>   ThreadManager::Impl::add ThreadManager not started

I see that a `ThreadManager` instance is being created in the constructor of `TThreadPoolServer` [here](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/9e864d57026b4905862108418ba9482892fb1f65/lib/cpp/src/thrift/server/TThreadPoolServer.h#L42). If a ThreadManager object has to be passed to the constructor of `TThreadPoolServer`, I am not sure why the constructor creates a `ThreadManager` object. I tried to create a `ThreadManger` object and call the `start()` method as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344431/apache-thrift-c-async-client) but the `PosixThreadFactory` is not part of the Thrift framework anymore. Do I have to implement the `ThreadFactory` abstract class? Can you please help me figure out this by providing a sample usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally find the Thrift [TestServer](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/cpp/src/TestServer.cpp) and [TestClient](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/cpp/src/TestClient.cpp) very good resources for getting started. They outline a broad range of possible options, including different server types. If you build from source, you can run the server and client from the command line. This makes it fairly easy to test a specific scenario before implementing it yourself.

For the `TThreadPoolServer` you can find the relevant section in the lines following [the TThreadPoolServer creation](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/9b9567b23378c821b460cfe54b70b9d189bf194d/test/cpp/src/TestServer.cpp#L771). That should show all required steps to set up a `TThreadPoolServer` with basic parameters.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to implement the server as a TThreadPoolServer and as TNonBlockingServer but couldn't find a way to collect the queue length at the server. If you do know a way of doing it, can you please answer this question -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226858/thrift-obtain-the-queue-length-at-a-server