# Obtain the queue length at a Thrift server

Tags: thrift

I am using `thrift` to implement a simple application. I would like to collect the queue length at a server i.e the number of requests that are pending service at the server. It could be either the queue length per client (connection) or total queue length at a server. I am playing around with different server types and thought the `ThreadManager` class would help since it collects server metrics. I created a server of type `TThreadPoolServer` but the methods like `ThreadManager::pendingTaskCount()` provide the number of connections that are pending service and not the number of requests that are pending service. The result was the same when I used a server of type `TNonblockingServer`. Can you please point me to a way to obtain the queue length?